# Rosbridge and roslibjs: Unable to load the manifest for package

Tags: ros, rosbridge, roslibjs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm trying the communication between javascript and Ros.

I use the example code of
"github.com/RobotWebTools/roslibjs/blob/develop/examples/simple.html "
with these changes:

```
var cmdVel = new ROSLIB.Topic({
    ros : ros,
    name : '/fromRos2Can',
    messageType : 'ackermann_msgs/AckermannDrive'    
  });
```

and

```
  var twist = new ROSLIB.Message({
    speed:1.0,
    acceleration:2.0,
    jerk:3.0,
    steering_angle:4.0,
    steering_angle_velocity:5.2
  });
```

and I receive these two error message:

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1404116229.210210] [Client 2] [id: advertise:/fromRos2Can:1] advertise: Unable to load the manifest for package ackermann_msgs. Caused by: ackermann_msgs

[ERROR] [WallTime: 1404116229.213060] [Client 2] [id: publish:/fromRos2Can:2] publish: Cannot infer topic type for topic /fromRos2Can as it is not yet advertised
```

**My c++ program works with AckermannDrive.msg** and a **test with a std_msg/String works too**.

Where is my mistake?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/179209/rosbridge-and-roslibjs:-unable-to-load-the-manifest-for-package/) by [genzostyle](https://answers.ros.org/users/13206/genzostyle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-06-30

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2014-07-09**:
Have you done source devel/setup.bash for you catkin_workspace in the terminal that rosbridge is running in?

What distro/ROS version are you running? Are they up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes I've done it, also because the test with the integer, instead AckermannDrive, works.

Hydro

---

Originally posted by [genzostyle](https://answers.ros.org/users/13206/genzostyle/) with karma: 36 on 2014-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0